# Docker dotnet core nginx proxy 502

Tags: symfony, nginx, docker, proxy, .net-core

I need to use dotnet core and nginx proxy server. I have two simple images and docker compose file. Dotnet app works well with correct ports. But when I use it with nginx, It is map to 80 I think. Nginx throw error 502.

My steps:

1. Create docker-compose file from: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy
2. Create dotnet app image with: *docker build --no-cache=true -t dotnetcoreimage .*
3. *docker-compose up*

Here is my app langsettings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://*:5000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express (Production)": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

App Docker file:

```
# FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build

#Update everytihing
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install bzip2

#remove force apt lists
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#for secure, copy to app folder
COPY . /app

RUN rm -Rf /app/node_modules

RUN rm -Rf /app/bower_components

#set workdir
WORKDIR /app

#set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Production"

#restore packages
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

#build c#
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

#npm install dependencies (webpack etc.)
RUN ["npm", "install"]

#run npm task webpack-prod
RUN ["npm", "run", "webpack-prod"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

# command to run
CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  mujcykloweb:
    image: mujcykloweb
    container_name: mujcyklowebcontainer       
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
```

When u run: *docker-compose up* and go to *http://localhost*

```
Creating network "cykloweb_default" with the default driver
Creating nginx-proxy
Creating mujcyklowebcontainer
Attaching to mujcyklowebcontainer, nginx-proxy
nginx-proxy    | forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5000
nginx-proxy    | forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5100
nginx-proxy    | dockergen.1 | 2017/01/14 16:16:36 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 2 containers
nginx-proxy    | dockergen.1 | 2017/01/14 16:16:36 Running 'nginx -s reload'
nginx-proxy    | dockergen.1 | 2017/01/14 16:16:36 Watching docker events
nginx-proxy    | dockergen.1 | 2017/01/14 16:16:36 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
mujcyklowebcontainer | Project app (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
mujcyklowebcontainer | Running Environment: Production
mujcyklowebcontainer | info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
mujcyklowebcontainer |       User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
mujcyklowebcontainer | Hosting environment: Production
mujcyklowebcontainer | Content root path: /app
mujcyklowebcontainer | Now listening on: http://+:80
mujcyklowebcontainer | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | 2017/01/14 16:16:58 [error] 25#25: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://334389048b872a533002b34d73f8c29fd09efc50/", host: "localhost:5050"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | localhost 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2017:16:16:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | localhost 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2017:16:16:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://localhost:5050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | 2017/01/14 16:16:58 [error] 25#25: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://334389048b872a533002b34d73f8c29fd09efc50/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:5050", referrer: "http://localhost:5050/"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | 2017/01/14 16:17:32 [error] 25#25: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://334389048b872a533002b34d73f8c29fd09efc50/", host: "localhost:5050"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | localhost 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2017:16:17:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | 2017/01/14 16:17:32 [error] 25#25: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://334389048b872a533002b34d73f8c29fd09efc50/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:5050", referrer: "http://localhost:5050/"
nginx-proxy    | nginx.1    | localhost 172.19.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2017:16:17:32 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://localhost:5050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
```

I think, that web app has bad port mapping, because 80 should have nginx or not? (Now listening on: http://+:80)

I tried to *docker composive --force-recreate* , stop/start docker and restart pc but the same problem.

Where is problem please?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Dockerfile expose 5000 port and application listen 5000 port. all right.
`EXPOSE 5000/tcp
CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]`
But why when did you run app it listen 80 port?
`mujcyklowebcontainer | Now listening on: http://+:80`
i am confused.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I am confused too, because without compose, only *dotnet run* listeing correctly port. Maybe some cache memory of docker? I don't know.

Comment: lets try expose app ports into docker-comose. try to add 
 `mujcykloweb:
   ports:
     - 5000:5000`
have you access to `http://localhost:5000` from host machine?

Comment: No, I got: *Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE* in my browser.

Comment: hmm, somebody listening 5000 port. May be is it your app? Has your app a access log? When you expose 5000 port, lets try access your app via nginx, please.

Comment: I probably solved this problem. I added *.UseUrls("http://*:5000")* to my app and remove it from lunchSettings. Now it works fine. I am not sure, if understand, but localhost:5000 didn't work, but *:5000 did.

Comment: @PetrTomášek If you think about docker container as an another computer it does not help if you listen on localhost. You have to listen on public interface to get through.